# Word delimiters in standard syntax table

Tags: syntax-table

I'm trying to configure other programs to emulate Emacs.

I know Emacs' word delimiters are:

1. User configurable
2. Mode dependent

But I'd still like to know what the default word boundary characters are. *Because* they are configurable and variable, I haven't found any lists.

I would love a list of the default word separators in `emacs-lisp-mode`. Of course, a description of how the delimiters vary by mode would be awesome too.

Comment: Other forum participants will undoubtedly give you more information, but I'll start off with the link to the syntax table documentation:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Tables.html

Comment: And also emacswiki: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsSyntaxTable

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand, in emacs -- word boundary is when next to a "w" syntax class stands char of some other class. This is in contrast to things like `sentence-end` which is determined by matching a regexp (`sentence-end` returns regexp).

Emacs lisp mode inherits `standard-syntax-table`:

```
;; from lisp-mode.el:
(defvar emacs-lisp-mode-syntax-table
  (let ((table (make-syntax-table))
  ..
```

(`make-syntax-table` is default to `standard-syntax-table`.)

The easiest way to browse `standard-syntax-table` is to enter `fundamental-mode` and call `describe-syntax` (<kbd>C-h s</kbd>).

Emacs lisp mode makes some tweaks to `standard-syntax-table`, of which I understand the following:

- `` `',@# `` are expression prefixes:

  ```
  (modify-syntax-entry ?` "'   " table)
  (modify-syntax-entry ?' "'   " table)
  (modify-syntax-entry ?, "'   " table)
  (modify-syntax-entry ?@ "'   " table)
  (modify-syntax-entry ?# "'   " table)
  ```
- `;` starts a comment, `\n` ends it:

  ```
  (modify-syntax-entry ?\; "<   " table)
  (modify-syntax-entry ?\n ">   " table)
  ```
- `\` is an escape char:

  ```
  (modify-syntax-entry ?\" "\"    " table)
  ```

Comment: A clear answer.